# Unifying associated type synonyms with class constraints

Tags: haskell, type-families

I have a nested type that I want to partially specify using associated type synonyms. Below is some extremely reduced code that demonstrates the problem:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies,
FlexibleInstances,
FlexibleContexts,
MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

f :: Int -> Int
f x = x+1

data X t i
newtype Z i = Z i deriving (Eq,Show)
newtype Y q = Y (T q)

class Qux m r where
    g :: (T m) -> r

class (Integral (T a)) => Foo a where
    type T a
    -- ... functions

instance (Integral i) => Foo (X (Z i) i) where
    type T (X (Z i) i) = i

instance (Foo q) => Num (Y q) -- where ...

instance (Foo q, Foo (X m' Int)) => Qux (X m' Int) (Y q) where
    g x =  fromIntegral $ f $ x
```

which (even with UndecidableInstances) leads to the compiler error:

```
Could not deduce (T (X m' Int) ~ Int)
```

I know that adding this constraint to the instance of Qux makes the compiler happy. However, I know that in my program (T (X arg1 arg2)) = arg2, so I am trying to figure out how to **not** have to write this constraint.

My question is: can I make Haskell realize that when I write 'Int' as the second parameter to X, that this is (identically) the same thing as the synonym T (X a' Int)? I realize I'm using "special" knowledge about how my instances will look, but I think there should be a way to convey this to the compiler.

Thanks

Comment: I'm having a hard time following this. Have you shown us the `Qux` class declaration? What does "other instances of Foo nested in the same way" mean? What does "make multiple instances depending on X but for generiz Z and fixed nested type i" mean? Moreover, many of your proposed constraints don't look well-kinded; "I have to add the constraint S (T (X a')) ~ Int" is one such. Even if you flesh that out to the constraint S (T (X a' i)) ~ Int, that doesn't look correct; perhaps you meant something like S (T (X a' i)) ~ a' instead? Overall, this question could use some proofreading.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Daniel, I hope my edits make the question easier to understand. To answer a few of your questions explicitly, the definition of Qux is pretty much irrelevant, it is just some class that I'm making an instance of. What I meant by "nested in the same way" is that all instance of Foo will have the same kind. (I think that's what I mean...) I hope that adding the alternate approach will clarify my constraints.

Comment: There wouldn't be any simple _example_ of what you want to do?

Comment: I should also mention the reason I'm bothering with the type synonyms at all: There are some cases where I want an instance (Foo a => Qux a), that doesn't restrict 'X' or 'i' (so I don't have direct access to the 'i' parameter). Another example is that I have a data (H x), where I intend x to be an instance of Foo. I then define H as (data H x = H (S (T x))), so that H doesn't have to carry around the type parameter S (T x).

Comment: The code now compiles. Removing the instance constraint (S (T (X m' Int)) ~ Int), which is what I am trying to figure out how to do, produces the compiler error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm not sure I understand the question yet, I'm going to discuss the code you wrote; perhaps some part of my rambling will either point you in a helpful direction or spark some pointed questions that are possible for me to answer. That is to say: warning! rambling non-answer ahead!

First, let's talk about the `Bar` class.

```
-- class (i ~ S b) => Bar b i where
--     type S b
--     ...
```

Since we know the constraint `i ~ S b`, we might as well drop the `i` argument, and I will do so for the rest of the discussion.

```
class Bar b where type S b
-- or, if the class is empty, just
-- type family S b
-- with no class declaration at all
```

Here's how the instances for this new class would look:

```
instance Bar (Z  i) where type S (Z  i) = i
instance Bar (Z' i) where type S (Z' i) = i
```

If this is meant to be true for *any* type constructor, you could consider writing this as one instance instead:

```
-- instance Bar (f i) where type S (f i) = i
```

Now, let's talk about the `Foo` class. To change it to match with the above, we would write

```
class Bar (T a) => Foo a where type T a
```

You've declared two instances:

```
-- instance (Bar (Z i) i) => Foo (X (Z i) i) where
--     type T (X (Z i) i) = Z i
--
-- instance (Bar (Z' i) i) => Foo (X' (Z' i) i) where
--     type T (X (Z' i) i) = Z' i
```

We can strip the second argument to `Bar` as before, but we can also do another thing: since we know there's a `Bar (Z i)` instance (we declared it above!), we can take away the instance constraint.

```
instance Foo (X (Z  i) i) where type T (X (Z  i) i) = Z  i
instance Foo (X (Z' i) i) where type T (X (Z' i) i) = Z' i
```

Whether you want to keep the `i` argument to `X` or not depends on what `X` is supposed to represent. So far, we haven't changed the semantics of any of the class declarations or data types -- only how they were declared and instanced. Changing `X` may not have the same property; it's hard to say without seeing the definition of `X`. With the data declarations and sufficiently many extensions, the above prelude compiles.

Now, your complaints:

- You say that the following doesn't compile:

  ```
  class Qux a
  instance Foo (X  a' Int) => Qux (X  a' Int)
  instance Foo (X' a' Int) => Qux (X' a' Int)
  ```

  But, with `UndecidableInstances`, that does compile here. And it makes sense for it to need `UndecidableInstances`: there's nothing to stop somebody from coming along later and declaring an instance like

  ```
  instance Qux (X Y Int) => Foo (X Y Int)

  Then, checking whether `Qux (X Y Int)` had an instance would require checking whether `Foo (X Y Int)` had an instance and vice versa. Loop.
  ```
- You say, "It also wants the instance constraint `S (T (X a'))) ~ Int`, even though I know that in my program, these are always just synonyms.". I don't know what the first "it" is -- I can't reproduce this error -- so I can't answer this very well. Also, as I complained before, this constraint is ill-kinded: `X :: (* -> *) -> * -> *`, therefore `X a' :: * -> *`, and `T` expects an argument of kind `*`. So I'm going to assume you meant `S (T (X a' Int)) ~ Int` instead.

  Despite these complaints, we can ask why `S (T (X a' Int)) ~ Int` is not provable from the assumptions we have so far. So far, we've only declared `Foo` instances for types that fit the pattern `X (Z i) i` and `X (Z' i) i`. So the type function `T` can only reduce when its argument type fits one of those patterns. The type `X a' Int` doesn't quite fit either of those patterns. We could cram it into the right pattern: we could try reducing with `X (Z Int) Int` instead (say). Then we would find that `T (X (Z Int) Int) ~ Z Int`, and therefore `S (T (X (Z Int) Int) ~ S (Z Int) ~ Int`.

  This answers how to fix the type-level reduction, but doesn't explain how to fix whatever code is not building. To do that, we'd have to find out why the type checker needs a coercion from `S (T (X a' Int))` to `Int`, and see if we can convince it that a more specific (and satisfiable) coercion like `S (T (X (Z Int) Int)) ~ Int`, or, with the suggested generalized `Bar` instance above, `S (T (X (f Int) Int)) ~ Int`. We certainly can't help you with that without having enough code to reproduce your error.
- You ask, "can I make Haskell realize that when I write 'Int' as the second parameter to X, that this is (identically) the same thing as the synonym S (T (X a' Int))?". I don't understand this question at all. You want to somehow have a provable equality `X a Int ~ S (T (X a' Int))`? That's the interpretation I get from a literal reading of your question.

  In context, I think you may have wanted to ask whether you can get a provable equality `b ~ S (T (X a b))`; in that case, the answer is, "Definitely!". We'll abuse the fact we know above that `b ~ S (Z b)` to reduce this equation to the stronger one `Z b ~ T (X a b)`. Then we can just replace the `Foo` instances above with one that makes this declaration and nothing more:

  ```
  instance Foo (X a b) where T (X a b) = Z b
  ```

  Alternately, we could postulate the other reasonable equation, `T (X a b) ~ a`; then, to prove that `S (T (X a b)) ~ b` we would just need to prove that `S a ~ b` (by reducing `T`), so we could write this other alternate `Foo` instance:

  ```
  instance (Bar a, S a ~ b) => Foo (X a b) where T (X a b) = a
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the response Daniel. I added simpler code that also demonstrates compiler error. Sorry for not doing this originally, everything I'm going to say will refer to the new code. I believe you found my question: How do I make T (X m Int) ~ Int provable? I'm confused about the difference between your 2nd and 3rd bullets, they seems similar to me (and I can't tell which one is the answer I'm looking for).

Comment: I was able to fix the compiler error (and dispense with the instance constraint) by adding a new instance:   instance (Integral i) => Foo (X a i) where
    type T (X a i) = i.    However, how does the compiler determine which instance to use? I've heard there is something where it can choose the most specific instance, is that what would happen here?

Comment: @Eric By default, instances are not allowed to overlap, and hence there is no "choosing" to be done -- at most one instance exists for any given type.

Comment: Do you have a good resource for learning about proving these kind of equality constraints?

Comment: @Eric I actually don't. The [original paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/ext-f/tldi22-sulzmann-with-appendix.pdf) is good, but focused on implementation of equality constraints rather than applications. You might search for introductions to GADTs; it turns out that these cover many of the use cases and in fact are just equalities in disguise.