# Using makeLenses, class constraints and type synonyms together

Tags: haskell

I'm quite new to Haskell and want to use `makeLenses` from `Control.Lens` and class constraints together with type synonyms to make my functions types more compact (readable?).

I've tried to come up with a minimal dummy example to demonstrate what I want to achieve and the example serves no other purpose than this.

At the end of this post I've added an example closer to my original problem if you are interested in the context.

**Minimal example**

As an example, say I define the following data type:

```
data State a = State { _a :: a
                     } deriving Show
```

, for which I also make lenses:

```
makeLenses ''State
```

In order to enforce a class constraint on the type parameter `a` used by the type constructor `State` I use a smart constructor:

```
mkState :: (Num a) =>  a -> State a
mkState n = State {_a = n}
```

Next, say I have a number of functions with type signatures similar to this:

```
doStuff :: Num a => State a -> State a
doStuff s = s & a %~ (*2)
```

This all works as intended, for example:

```
test = doStuff . mkState $ 5.5 -- results in State {_a = 11.0}
```

**Problem**

I've tried to use the following type synonym:

```
type S = (Num n) => State n -- Requires the RankNTypes extensions
```

, together with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
```

, in an attempt to simplify the type signature of `doStuff`:

```
doStuff :: S -> S
```

, but this gives the following error:

```
Couldn't match type `State a0' with `forall n. Num n => State n'
    Expected type: a0 -> S
    Actual type: a0 -> State a0
In the second argument of `(.)', namely `mkState'
    In the expression: doStuff . mkState
    In the expression: doStuff . mkState $ 5.5
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

**Question**

My current knowledge of Haskell is not sufficient to understand what causes the above error. I hope someone can explain what causes the error and/or suggest other ways to construct the type synonym or why such a type synonym is not possible.

**Background**

My original problem looks closer to this:

```
data State r = State { _time :: Int
                     , _ready :: r
                     } deriving Show

makeLenses ''State

data Task = Task { ... }
```

Here I want to enforce the type of `_ready` being an instance of the `Queue` class using the following smart constructor:

```
mkState :: (Queue q) => Int -> q Task -> State (q Task)
mkState t q  = State { _time = t
                     , _ready = q
                     }
```

I also have a number of functions with type signatures similar to this:

```
updateState :: Queue q => State (q Task) -> Task -> State (q Task)
updateState s x = s & ready %~ (enqueue x) & time %~ (+1)
```

I would like to use a type synonym `S` to be able to rewrite the type of such functions as:

```
updateState :: S -> Task -> S
```

, but as with the first minimal example I don't know how to define the type synonym `S` or whether it is possible at all.

Maybe there is no real benefit in trying to simplify the type signatures?

**Related reading**

I've read the following related questions on SO:

- [Class constraints for data records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585891/class-constraints-for-data-records)
- [Are type synonyms with typeclass constraints possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232829/are-type-synonyms-with-typeclass-constraints-possible)

This might also be related but given my current understanding of Haskell I cannot really understand all of it:

- [Unifying associated type synonyms with class constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493603/unifying-associated-type-synonyms-with-class-constraints)

**Follow-up**

It's been a while since I've had the opportunity to do some Haskell. Thanks to @bheklilr I've now managed to introduce a type synonym only to hit the next type error I'm still not able to understand. I've posted the following follow-up question [Type synonym causes type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31772516/type-synonym-causes-type-error) regarding the new type error.

Comment: What a well-asked question. Well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see that error in particular because of the combination of the `.` operator and your use of `RankNTypes`.  If you change it from

```
test = doStuff . mkState $ 5.5
```

to

```
test = doStuff $ mkState 5.5
```

or even

```
test = doStuff (mkState 5.5)
```

it will compile.  Why is this?  Look at the types:

```
doStuff :: forall n. Num n => State n -> State n
mkState :: Num n => n -> State n

(doStuff) . (mkState) <===> (forall n. Num n => State n -> State n) . (Num n => n -> State n)
```

Hopefully the parentheses help make it clear here, the `n` from `forall n. Num n ...` for `doStuff` is a different type variable from the `Num n => ...` for `mkState` because the scope of the `forall` only extends to the end of the parentheses.  So these functions can't actually compose because the compiler sees them as separate types!  There are actually special rules for the `$` operator specifically for using the `ST` monad precisely for this reason, just so you can do `runST $ do ...`.

You may be able to accomplish what you want easier using GADTs, but I don't believe `lens`' `TemplateHaskell` will work with GADT types.  However, you can write your own pretty easily in this case, so it isn't that big of a deal.

---

A further explanation:

```
doStuff . mkState $ 5.5
```

is very different than

```
doStuff $ mkState 5.5
```

In the first one, `doStuff` says that *for all* `Num` types `n`, its type is `State n -> State n`, whereas `mkState` says *for some* `Num` type `m`, its type is `m -> State m`.  These two types are not the same because of the "for all" and "for some" quantifications (hence `ExistentialQuantification`), since composing them would mean that for some `Num m` you can produce all `Num n`.

In the `doStuff $ mkState 5.5`, you have the equivalent of

```
(forall n. Num n => State n -> State n) $ (Num m => State m)
```

Notice that the type after the `$` is not a function because `mkState 5.5` is fully applied.  So this works because *for all* `Num n` you can do `State n -> State n`, and you're providing it some `Num m => State m`.  This works intuitively.  Again, the difference here is the composition versus application.  You can't compose a function that works on some types with a function that works on all types, but you can pass a value to a function that works on all types ("all types" here meaning `forall n. Num n => n`).

Comment: Thank you @bheklilr, it kind of make sense although I'm not yet fully understand why changing to `doStuff $ mkState 5 <==> (forall n. Num n => State n -> State n) $ (Num n => n -> State n) `  resolves this. As far as I understand we now have `doStuff $ mkState 5 <==> (forall n. Num n => State n -> State n) $ (State Integer) `.  Is it because of the special rules for the `$` operator you mention that the compiler now is able to deduce that `n` on the left hand side of  `$` must be `Integer`?

Comment: I've briefly looked into [GADTs as an alternative solution for the class constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505975/write-gadt-record-with-constrained-type) beforeposting this question but since I'm new to Haskell and lenses I thought I was better off using `makeLenses` compared to [making my own lenses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28145369/makelenses-for-gadts-haskell). I might investigate how to define my own lenses once I get more experienced with Haskell and lenses.

Comment: Perhaps you (@KarlMarklund) intended to write `(doStuff . mkState) $ 5.5` instead of `doStuff . mkState $ 5.5`. Thus the problem seems to be related to operator precedence, thus parsing, and not anything more complicated.

Comment: @DaveClarke Before introducing the type synonym `doStuff . mkState $ 5.5` worked but after introducing the type synonym it caused an error. I'm now trying to understand the answer given by @bheklilr.

Comment: Excellent @bheklilr! The added explanation was precisely what I needed. Now it all makes sense and I look forward to learn more about Haskell and the Haskell type system.

Comment: @KarlMarklund: I spoke to soon.

Comment: @bheklilr Adding and using the type synonym worked but only for integers and not for floats, see my update to the original post.