# Type synonym causes type error

Tags: haskell

As a follow-up to my previous question [Using makeLenses, class constraints and type synonyms together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30582583/using-makelenses-class-constraints-and-type-synonyms-together) I've got a new type error I would like to understand.

The type error is caused by the introduction of the type synonym `type S = (Num n) => State n` in the below example.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}                                                                                                                              
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}                                                                                                                                   

module Foo where                                                                                                                                              

import Control.Lens                                                                                                                                           

data State a = State { _a :: a                                                                                                                                
                     } deriving Show                                                                                                                          

makeLenses ''State -- Requires TemplateHaskell                                                                                                                

-- | Smart constructor enforcing class constraint on record field _a.                                                                                         
mkState :: (Num a) =>  a -> State a                                                                                                                           
mkState n = State {_a = n}                                                                                                                                    

doStuff1 :: Num a => State a -> State a                                                                                                                       
doStuff1 s = s & a %~ (*2)                                                                                                                                    

test1a = doStuff1 $ mkState  5   -- results in State {_a = 10.0}                                                                                              
test1b = doStuff1 $ mkState  5.5 -- results in State {_a = 11.0}                                                                                                                                                           

type S = (Num n) => State n -- Requires the RankNTypes extensions                                                                                             

doStuff2 :: S -> S                                                                                                                                            
doStuff2 s = s & a %~ (*2)                                                                                                                                    

test2a = doStuff2 $ mkState  5   -- Results in State {_a = 10.0}                                                                                              
--test2b = doStuff2 $ mkState  5.5 -- Type error.
```

If I uncomment `test2b` I get the following error.

```hs
Could not deduce (Fractional n) arising from the literal `5.5'
from the context (Num n)
  bound by a type expected by the context: Num n => State n
  at Foo.hs:32:10-32
Possible fix:
  add (Fractional n) to the context of
    a type expected by the context: Num n => State n
In the first argument of `mkState', namely `5.5'
In the second argument of `($)', namely `mkState 5.5'
In the expression: doStuff2 $ mkState 5.5
```

I would like to be able to understand why the introduced type synonym causes this error and how to decipher the error message.

Comment: BTW the `(Num n) => State n` syntax without a preceding `forall n.` is [deprecated in GHC 7.10, and will be disabled entirely in 7.12](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/docs/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#univ).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`S -> S` is not equivalent to `forall n. Num n => State n -> State n`. It's equivalent to `(forall n. Num n => State n) -> (forall n. Num n => State n)`. The former would mean that, for all numeric types `n`, we can pass in a `State n` and get back a `State n` (for the same type `n`). The latter means that we pass in something that can be a `State n` for all numeric types `n` and we get back something that can be a `State n` for all type `n`. In other words both the argument and the result are polymorphic.

What this means is that the argument you pass in must have type `Num n => State n`, not a more concrete type like, say, `State Int`. This is true for `5`, which has the type `Num n => n`, but not `5.5`, which has the type `Fractional n => n`.

Comment: Thank you @sepp2k! As a Haskell beginner I've find the type system very interesting and hope to learn more about how to reason about polymorphic types.